# Can all convolutional neural networks be used with images of any number of channels?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network, tensor

Like for example can i use the same cnn with grayscale images and RGB/coloured images?

Comment: You cannot do this unless you adapt the model to accept a different input shape.  One trivial way is to triplicate the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any pre-processing, definitely no. When you build and train your neural network you need to know the input shape. eg: 25x25xn where n is the number of channels.

What you can do is make a Fully Convolutional Neural Network, so that you can input a nxn image. Here is better explanation on it:

https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-a-fully-convolutional-network-fcn-in-tensorflow-2-3c46fb61de3b

other approach is to process your input to have the shape you need. In your case, you can copy and past a grey scale image for the others 2 channels or grey scale the RGB image. But you will need to have fix input shape.

It's actually very common to pre-processing images before input it to a NN. E.G crop, rescale, grayscale, normalization or even filters, so that your input images have a know shape and are similar to your training set.

Comment: To expand on this, you cannot use arbitrary number of channels because the number of channels affects the depth of the first set of filters in a CNN. With a fully convolutional neural network, you can pass in any size, but the number of channels must be constant. The filters are translationally invariant, but they depend on a constant number of channels.